# QEMU Triple Faulting when enabling interrupts

Tags: c++, c, assembly, kernel

I'm working on a simple operating system, and I'm currently trying to load the IDT. I'm not getting any errors during compilation, but QEMU is triple faulting when I try to enable interrupts.

I have looked at the address in the EIP register with iHex, but it seems to be auto generated code because it is nowhere in the kernel code. I have also tried loading the GDT in my c++ code, but it didn't make a difference and I have already loaded it in my boot loader.

IDT Install function

```
void idt_install()
{
    /* Sets the special IDT pointer up, just like in 'gdt.c' */
    idtp.limit = (sizeof (struct idt_entry) * 256) - 1;
    idtp.base = (unsigned int) idt;

    /* Clear out the entire IDT, initializing it to zeros */
    memset(&idt, 0, sizeof(struct idt_entry) * 256);

    /* Add any new ISRs to the IDT here using idt_set_gate */



    /* Points the processor's internal register to the new IDT */
    idt_load();
}
```

Relavent code in kernel_init function
idt_install();

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("sti");
```

It should load the IDT and enable interrupts however I get a triple fault and QEMU repeatedly reboots. Here are the results of running QEMU with -d int option.

```
EAX=000000fa EBX=000b8022 ECX=000b8000 EDX=00000060
ESI=00007e12 EDI=00000000 EBP=0000de88 ESP=0000de70
EIP=00007e4a EFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c43 00000018
IDT=     000096c0 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000de54 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0042 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00007e4a pc=00007e4a SP=0010:0000de70 env->regs[R_EAX]=000000fa
EAX=000000fa EBX=000b8022 ECX=000b8000 EDX=00000060
ESI=00007e12 EDI=00000000 EBP=0000de88 ESP=0000de70
EIP=00007e4a EFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c43 00000018
IDT=     000096c0 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000de54 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     2: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00007e4a pc=00007e4a SP=0010:0000de70 env->regs[R_EAX]=000000fa
EAX=000000fa EBX=000b8022 ECX=000b8000 EDX=00000060
ESI=00007e12 EDI=00000000 EBP=0000de88 ESP=0000de70
EIP=00007e4a EFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c43 00000018
IDT=     000096c0 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000de54 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just fixed this. I was forgetting to run my install_isrs function. I don't know why this took me days to realize, but if anyone else is having this issue, all I can say is make sure you're not missing one line of code that will ruin your whole kernel.

Comment: I've read that BOCHS is useful for debugging because its built-in debugger understands segmentation.  IDK if it has any other features that would help debug interrupt descriptor tables after you've already switched to protected mode (presumably with a flat memory model).

Comment: @PeterCordes : BOCHS `info idt` command is useful to dump the interrupt vector table and the contents of the IDT record (base and length)

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you I am running into this issue again for some reason so I will be sure to try this

Comment: @MineceptionDoesStuff : if you put your project on Github or other site I could take a look at it.